# Raphaeljs adding click events to a slice of the Pie chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I need to respond to a click event on each slice in a Raphael Pie Chart. I tried it this way, but it does not seem to do it.  My code is just two lines commented as "My code" in the below code, which comes directly from the demo Pie Chart of RaphaelJS...

```
        <script>
        var u = "";
        var r = "";
        window.onload = function () {

            r = Raphael("holder"),
                pie = r.piechart(320, 240, 100, [25, 20, 13, 32, 5, 21, 14, 10,41,16,12,18,16,14,12,13], 
                    { legend: ["%%.%% - Enterprise Users", "IE Users"],
                    legendpos: "west", href: ["http://raphaeljs.com", "http://g.raphaeljs.com"]
                    }
                );

            r.text(320, 100, "Interactive Pie Chart").attr({ font: "20px sans-serif" });

            pie.hover(function () {
                u = this;                 // My Code   
                u.onclick = clickEvent;   //  hook to the function 
               this.sector.stop();
                this.sector.scale(1.1, 1.1, this.cx, this.cy);  // Scale slice 

                if (this.label) {                               // Scale button and bolden text 
                    this.label[0].stop();
                    this.label[0].attr({ r: 7.5 });
                    this.label[1].attr({ "font-weight": 800 });
                }
            }, function () {
                this.sector.animate({ transform: 's1 1 ' + this.cx + ' ' + this.cy }, 500, "bounce");


                if (this.label) {
                    this.label[0].animate({ r: 5 }, 1500, "bounce");
                    this.label[1].attr({ "font-weight": 400 });
                }
            });

        };
        function clickEvent(){
            console.log("Clicked!")
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are attaching the click event in the hover event? It would seem more correct to do `pie.onclick = clickEvent` outside of the hover function

Comment: @ShanRobertson  I need to trigger on each slice.  Slices have subgroups, so clicking on then makes a request for new data which expands into a different pie chart.  This may go on for a few levels down.  Basically a drill down situation.  Thank you for the reply anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Raphaels syntax is a little different.

Check this [documentation](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.click)

Your code should be as below:

```
u.click(clickEvent);
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, but that is the first thing I tried, after reading the Raphael documentation.  But it does not respond to that.  Nevertheless I thank you for trying to help.  I found the solution and will post it when I get a moment.  I will also have to ask the creator of Raphael about that...